# Swift: Auto Layout - Columns of Text - removing trailing and leading warnings

Tags: swift, autolayout, uilabel

[image]

I have two columns of text. The left is anchored top, left and bottom and the righthand side conversely. This still generates leading and trailing warnings. How do I connect the two columns' rows to tell Auto Layout to just expand the space in between?

Comment: Even I don't understand what you mean by "just expand the space in between". I'm not sure how AutoLayout can understand what you want... What exactly are the warnings messages?

Comment: Without seeing the *specific* warnings, I'd have to guess that they involve *intrinsic width* and the fact that there's a possibility of overlapping columns, based on the contents of the labels. You should (somehow) fully define things. A specific width, a less than or equal to width, maybe even prioritize something. Looking at your screenshot, why is the width of the top left two labels different? It's because of their intrinsic width.

Comment: Warning is: Trailing constraint is missing which may cause overlap with other views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ***YOU*** know exactly what text you're going to put into those labels, Storyboard / Interface Builder (IB) has no idea.

So this looks great to you:

[image]

But... what happens if the "Date" text changes to *"When do you want to get started?"*:

[image]

Because we haven't given a constraint between the two labels, they overlap.

So, let's do the same thing on both "rows" but, add a Trailing-to-Leading constraint of `8` between the labels:

[image]

We've prevented the **overlap** but now we see a new problem (that IB will warn you about)... ***Which*** label should get compressed? IB (and auto-layout at run-time) will make its own decision, which may not be what you want, and which may be inconsistent between similar layouts.

To fix that, we give a higher **Content Compression Resistance Priority** to the label we do ***not*** want compressed:

[image]

And here is the result - top "row" has the left-hand label at the default of 750, and the right-hand label at 751, and the bottom "row" has the left-hand label at 751, and the right-hand label at the default of 750:

[image]

It looks the same as "C" but we no longer have errors/warnings from IB.

So, even if you know the text in your two columns will never be enough to overlap, IB is going to encourage you to provide enough constraints (and priority settings) to make sure you get exactly what you want.

Comment: This makes complete sense. Item B - can I add the "Trailing-to-Leading" constraint through the U/I? Most of the Googling answers seems to refer to doing it programatically.

Comment: I can add a Trailing and Leading separately but the way you wrote the term seemed to imply there was an integrated option. If I do this altering the priorities still leaves me with the red warning lines.

Comment: Also wanted the Content Hugging Priority altered. Very many thanks, this had been eluding me for days.

Comment: @EdwardHasted - in Storyboard, Ctlr-Drag from the left label to the right label. Select `Horizontal Spacing` from the popup. It will default to the current distance, so edit that new constraint and change the constant to 8 (or however much space you want between the labels).

Comment: Thanks and once again for such a well laid out explanation.